# Valgrind on MIPS Reports no Heap Usage

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, mips, valgrind

I'm using valgrind (v3.10.0) to hunt down a memory leak in a complex application (a heavily modified build of net-snmp) that is being built as part of a bigger software suite. I am sure there is a leak (the memory footprint of the application grows linearly without bound), but valgrind always reports the following upon termination.

```
==1139== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1139==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1139==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==1139== 
==1139== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

The total heap usage cannot be zero -- there are many, many calls to `malloc` and `free` throughout the application. Valgrind is still capable of finding "Invalid Write" errors.

The application in question is being compiled, along with other software packages, with a uclibc-gcc toolchain for the MIPS processor (uclibc v0.9.29) to be flashed onto an embedded device running a busybox (v1.17.2) linux shell. I am running valgrind directly on the device. I use the following options when launching Valgrind:

```
--tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --undef-value-errors=no --trace-children=yes
```

**Basically, Valgrind doesn't detect any heap usage even though I've used the heap.** Why might this be? Are any of my assumptions (below) wrong?

---

### What I've Tried

#### Simple Test Program

I compiled the simple test program (using the same target and toolchain as the application above) from the Valgrind [quick-start tutorial](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html), to see if Valgrind would detect the leak. The final output was the same as above: no heap usage.

#### Linking Issues?

Valgrind documentation has the following to say on [their FAQ](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.hiddenbug):

> If your program is statically linked, most Valgrind tools will only work well if they are able to replace certain functions, such as malloc, with their own versions. By default, statically linked malloc functions are not replaced. A key indicator of this is if Memcheck says "All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible".

The above sounds exactly like my problem, so I checked to see that it's dynamically linked to the C libraries that contained `malloc` and `free`. I used the uclibc toolchain's custom `ldd` executable ([I can't use the native linux `ldd`](http://www.uclibc.org/FAQ.html#ldd)) and the output included the following lines:

```
libc.so.0 => not found (0x00000000)
/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 => /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 (0x00000000)
```

(The reason they're not found is because I'm running this on the x86 host device; the mips target device doesn't have an ldd executable.) Based on my understanding, `malloc` and `free` will be in one of these libraries, and they seem to be dynamically linked. I also did `readelf` and `nm` on the executable to confirm that the references to `malloc` and `free` are undefined (which is characteristic of a dynamically linked executable).

Additionally, I tried launching Valgrind with the `--soname-synonyms=somalloc=NONE` option as suggested by the FAQ.

#### LD_PRELOAD support?

As pointed out by commenters and answerers, Valgrind depends upon usage of LD_PRELOAD. It has been suggested that my toolchain doesn't support this feature. In order to confirm that it does, I followed [this example](http://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-linker-tricks-using-ld_preload-to-cheat-inject-features-and-investigate-programs/) to create a simple test library and load it (I replaced `rand()` with a function that just returns 42). The test worked, so it would seem that my target supports LD_PRELOAD just fine.

#### Elf Data

I'll also include some information from the `readelf` command which may be useful. Rather than a giant dump, I've trimmed things down to include only what may be relevant.

```
Dynamic section
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libnetsnmpagent.so.30]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libnetsnmpmibs.so.30]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libnetsnmp.so.30]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.0]
 0x0000000f (RPATH)                      Library rpath: [//lib]

Symbol table '.dynsym'
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
    27: 00404a40     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND free
    97: 00404690     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND malloc
```

Comment: did you give the **--trace-children=yes** option? cause if you use **exec**, you must put that option

Comment: @yakoudbz i wasn't originally using that option, but i am now, and the outcome is unchanged. thank you for the advice. i've edited the post to show which options i'm using.

Comment: Are you sure the memory used does not grow because of the forks, but because of memory leaks?

Comment: @yakoudbz that's a possibility, but i don't think the heap usage should be zero regardless.

Comment: I recall a similar issue where uClibC was not built with LD_PRELOAD support, which Valgrind depends on. Can you test if that's your problem? If so, enabling LD_PRELOAD support when building uClibC should do the trick.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis hmm, i'm not sure we build uclibc during the build process. thank you for the advice, i will look into it and report back.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis after quite a bit of digging, i've determined that we're using an old version of uclibc (0.9.29) in which LD_PRELOAD is permanently enabled and can't be turned off (as best as I can tell).

Comment: A possible reason might be that the redirection mechanism does not redirect the malloc calls to the valgrind interception, due to the uclibc soname not being the expected name. If that is the case, use --soname-synonyms=somalloc=xxxxxx where xxxxxx is the soname of the uclibc library

Comment: Can you add the output of `ldd $executable` to your question to confirm you aren't statically linking uclibc?

Comment: @b4hand I've made an edit to the post. The results left me confused.

Comment: @phd I've tried setting the soname to "NONE", which, according to [this mailing list post](http://valgrind.10908.n7.nabble.com/malloc-a-new-lib-not-in-uclibc-and-we-could-not-use-valgrind-could-you-give-me-some-advice-td33358.html), should allow substitution with whatever malloc library is used (as best as I can understand). To my knowledge, though, uclibc uses the typical name for standard libraries.

Comment: apparently you're running on the wrong architecture : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807560/ldd-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-linked-binary, please try to install all of the necessary compatibility-libraries and run ldd again

Comment: Did you try creating a dummy program which you are even more sure creates a leak, just to validate that Valgrind is not able to see that, either? I notice that Valgrind support for MIP32 is very new, perhaps there are issues. I do expect quality from Valgrind however, so that seems unlikely.

Comment: @phd in fact, according to the uclibc readme file, uclibc actually appears as a gnu libc library to applications: "there is an unwholesomely huge amount of code out there that depends on the presence of gnu libc header files. we have gnu libc compatible header files. [...] we lie and claim to be gnu libc in order to force these applications to work as their developers intended."

Comment: @unwind creating a new application in our architecture is not trivial. i have put an intentional leak in the application i'm trying to test, and i have tried testing other applications. i always get a result that says zero heap usage.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow OK. This seems gnarly and annoying, I hope you can resolve it.

Comment: since you seem to ignore resolution-attempts i shall now let you bathe in cluelessness.

Comment: @specializt I was reading up on the `ldd` command. See my most recent edit, I was typing it as you commented.

Comment: Use your cross compiled ldd from uclibc, that's what the faq to which you linked says will work. You could still have **a shared library** while statically linking to uclibc.

Comment: Also what version of valgrind are you using? MIPS support was added in 3.8.0.

Comment: @b4hand I'm using v3.10.0. Will update with results of `ldd` momentarily.

Comment: @unwind i did end up creating a dummy program. i copied the exact test program from [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html). the valgrind output was the same as i posted in my question (no leaks detected).

Comment: Could you post the output of valgrind with the `-v --trace-redir=yes` option?

Comment: Have you considered trying [Boehm GC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector)? It can be used for [leak detection](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/leak.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Adding another answer as the question itself has changed substantially after OP awarded the first bounty)*

Based on my understanding of your edits, you have now:

1. Replicated the problem with `valgrind`'s own test program
2. Confirmed the test program binary is dynamically linked to `uclibc`
3. Confirmed `LD_PRELOAD` is working on your system
4. Confirmed (if only by using the test program) that this isn't symbol interference from another library

To me, that indicates that `valgrind` has a bug or is incompatible with your toolchain. I found references to say it should work with your tool-chain, so that implies to me there is a bug either way.

I suggest therefore that you report a bug using the mechanism described [here](http://valgrind.org/support/bug_reports.html). Perhaps leave out the bit about your complicated application, and just point out the simple test program doesn't work. If you haven't already, you might try the users mailing list as described [here](http://valgrind.org/support/mailing_lists.html).

Comment: thank you for your answer. i find it more likely that i'm misunderstanding one of my preconceptions than that there is a fundamental bug; nevertheless, i do have an open message on the mailing list, and if that fails to uncover any misconceptions on my part, i shall try filing a bug report.

Answer (score 11):

First, let's do a real test to see whether something is statically linked.

```
$ ldd -v /bin/true
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffdc502000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0731e11000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f07321ec000)

    Version information:
    /bin/true:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

The second line in the output shows it is dynamically linked to `libc`, which is what contains `malloc`.

As for what might be going wrong, I can suggest four things:

1. Perhaps it's not linked to normal `libc`, but to some other C library (e.g. `uclibc`) or something else `valgrind` is not expecting. The above test will show you exactly what it's linked to. In order for `valgrind` to work, it uses `LD_PRELOAD` to wrap the `malloc()` and `free()` functions (description of general function wrapping [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.wrapping)). If your `libc` substitute doesn't support `LD_PRELOAD` or (somehow) the C library's `malloc()` and `free()` aren't being used at all (with those names), then `valgrind` is not going to work. Perhaps you could include the link line used when you build your application.
2. It is leaking, but it's not allocating memory using `malloc()`. For instance, it might (unlikely) be doing its own calls to `brk()`, or (more likely) allocating memory with `mmap`. You can use this to find out (this was a dump of `cat` itself).

.

```
$ cat /proc/PIDNUMBERHERE/maps
00400000-0040b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 805303                             /bin/cat
0060a000-0060b000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 805303                             /bin/cat
0060b000-0060c000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 805303                             /bin/cat
02039000-0205a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fbc8f418000-7fbc8f6e4000 r--p 00000000 08:01 1179774                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7fbc8f6e4000-7fbc8f899000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1573024                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7fbc8f899000-7fbc8fa98000 ---p 001b5000 08:01 1573024                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7fbc8fa98000-7fbc8fa9c000 r--p 001b4000 08:01 1573024                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7fbc8fa9c000-7fbc8fa9e000 rw-p 001b8000 08:01 1573024                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7fbc8fa9e000-7fbc8faa3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fbc8faa3000-7fbc8fac5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1594541                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fbc8fca6000-7fbc8fca9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fbc8fcc3000-7fbc8fcc5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fbc8fcc5000-7fbc8fcc6000 r--p 00022000 08:01 1594541                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fbc8fcc6000-7fbc8fcc8000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 1594541                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fffe1674000-7fffe1695000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffe178d000-7fffe178f000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Note whether the end address of `[heap]` is actually growing, or whether you are seeing additional `mmap` entries. Another good indicator of whether `valgrind` is working is to send a `SIGSEGV` or similar to the process and see whether you see heap in use on exit.

3. It isn't leaking in the strict sense, but it is leaking to all intents and purposes. For instance, perhaps it has datastructure (like a cache), which grows over time. On exit, the program (correctly) frees all entries in the cache. So, on exit, nothing is in use on the heap. In this instance, you'll want to know what is growing. This is a harder proposition. I'd use the technique to kill the program (above), capture the output, and post-process it. If you see 500 things after 24 hours, 1,000 after 48 hours, and 1,500 after 72 hours, that should give you an indication of what is 'leaking'. However, as *haris* points out in the comments, whilst this would result in the memory not being shown as leaks, it doesn't explain the 'total heap usage' being zero, as this describes the total allocations made and freed.
4. Perhaps `valgrind` is just not working on your platform. What happens if you build a very simple program like the one below, and run `valgrind` on it on your platform? If this isn't working, you need to find out *why* `valgrind` is not operating right. Note that `valgrind` on MIPS is pretty new. [Here](https://lists.openwrt.org/pipermail/openwrt-devel/2011-September/012252.html) is an email thread where a developer with MIPS and uclibc discovers `valgrind` is not reporting any allocations. His solution is to replace `ntpl` with `linuxthreads`.

.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  void *p = malloc (100);       /* does not leak */
  void *q = malloc (100);       /* leaks */
  free (p);
  exit (0);
}
```

Comment: `It isn't leaking in the strict sense, but it is leaking to all intents and purposes. For instance, perhaps it has datastructure (like a cache), which grows over time.`

anything that grows with time (perhaps the growth depends on the activity of the application) should be using dynamic memory allocation, then those allocations and free should have appeared in the valgrind output. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @haris `valgrind` does not show allocations which are freed on exit, only ones which are not freed before exit.

Comment: i tried with a simple `malloc()` and `free()`, and in heap summary it came `total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 4 bytes allocated`

Comment: @haris - ah - on the 'total heap usage' line - yes you are correct. I will adjust my answer.

Comment: **1.** the executable is linked dynamically to both lic.so and uclibc.so. i believe, but i'm not 100% sure, that my uclibc build has LD_PRELOAD support... but i've also tried setting the soname-synonyms option for valgrind, and that didn't work. **2.** there are definitely `malloc` calls in the code, so the heap shouldn't be empty even if the leak comes from `mmap` or other allocation methods. **3.** same as previous, the heap oughtn't be empty.

Comment: **4.** I did build a test program, I built the sample that Valgrind has on their quickstart page. It did not detect any heap usage or leaks. I am currently looking into that email thread you linked, to determine if it still applies to the version of valgrind i'm running and to determine if i can use linuxthreads instead of ntpl. thank you for your exceptionally detailed answer here, it has been very helpful in ruling things out for me and suggesting some new paths to look down.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow if you are linked to both `libc.so` and `uclibc.so` that may well be the issue, as `valgrind` is only going to override one `malloc()` implementation, and being linked to two is going to confuse it. I suspect it has the potential to confuse more than `valgrind` though!

Answer (score 1):

> In order to confirm that the executable is not statically linked, I ran file snmpd

Your problem is most likely not that the binary is statically linked (you now know it is not), but that `malloc` and `free` are statically linked into it (perhaps you are using alternative malloc implementation, such as `tcmalloc`?).

When you built the simple test case (on which Valgrind worked correctly), you likely didn't use the same link command line (and the same libraries) as your real application does.

In any case, it is trivial to check:

```
readelf -Ws snmpd | grep ' malloc'
```

If this shows `UND` (i.e. undefined), the Valgrind should have no trouble intercepting it. But chances are it shows `FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT ... malloc` instead, which means that your `snmpd` is *as good as statically linked* as far as valgrind is concerned.

Assuming my guess is correct, relink `snmpd` with `-Wl,-y,malloc` flag. That will tell you which library defines your `malloc`. Remove it from the link, find and fix the leak, then decide whether having that library is worth the trouble it has caused you.

Comment: The output says both "GLOBAL DEFAULT" and "UND". `97: 00404690     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND malloc` and `89: 00404690     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND malloc`

Comment: follow-up: i ran the `nm` command, and references to malloc and free are marked "U", so they're undefined.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Can you also run `readelf` on the simple test case? The fact that `readelf` shows both non-`0` address and `UND` for `malloc` is surprising to me.

Comment: Sure, the output is basically the same: `14: 004007f0     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND malloc` and `54: 004007f0     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND malloc`. The strange output is probably because I'm using readelf on an x86 machine, but the executables are MIPS executables.