# shared object library not found when running program, but it's linked during compiling

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++

Update: issue is solved. The library was Made for Armv7a CPUs but it was "soft float" Not "hard float". It seems like my machine is HF and Not SF compatible

My program depends on an externally build .so library called libMyLib.so. When I compile the program like this:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o run -pthread
```

it reports that there are a lot of undefined references, obviously because i didn't include libMyLib.so when compiling. So the compiler knows what he needs to compile the program. When i compile the program like this:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o run -pthread -lMyLib
```

it doesn't report any errors and creates the file "run". Notice that libMyLib.so is already in /usr/local/lib and it looks like it is linked when compiling since the references are defined now and the "run" file is created. But as i run the file, this happens:

```
$ ./run
    ./run: error while loading shared libraries: libMyLib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've checked with ldd and it shows me this:

```
$ ldd run
    ...
    libMyLib.so => not found
    ...
```

So ldd doesn't find the library on execution, but it finds it while compiling. I'm quite new to Linux and linking libraries so i don't know what to do.

Also, running ldd on the .so file returns this:

```
$ ldd /usr/local/lib/libMyLib.so
    not a dynamic executable
```

I've already checked an this message may occur when running a .so file on the wrong platform. But i've checked, the library is compiled for arm (I'm running on a raspberry pi -> arm):

```
$  objdump -f /usr/local/lib/libMyLib.so | grep ^architecture
    architecture: arm, flags 0x00000150:
```

I also update the linker:

```
$ sudo ldconfig -v
...
/usr/local/lib:
    libwiringPi.so -> libwiringPi.so.2.44
    libwiringPiDev.so -> libwiringPiDev.so.2.44
    libMyLib.so -> libMyLib.so.1
...
```

I really have no clue why this might still happen. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 8):

`/usr/local/lib` is one of the directories that the linker searches by default
for libraries specified with the `-l` option, so your linkage succeeds.

At runtime however, the program loader by default searches for the linked
libraries in:-

- `/lib`, `/usr/lib` and among the libraries whose names and locations have been cached in the `ldconfig` cache, `/etc/ld.so.cache`.
- The directories listed in the value of the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`,
  in the current shell.

The `ldconfig` cache is only updated when `ldconfig` is run. See [man `ldconfig`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig).

The loader fails to find `libMyLib.so` at runtime because you have not
run `ldconfig` since you placed that library in `/usr/local/lib` and
neither have you correctly added `/usr/local/lib` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
in the same shell in which you try to run the program.

It is inconvenient and otherwise undesirable to require a special setting of
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to enable a program to run.

To enable the loader to find your library, run `ldconfig` as root. This
will succeed provided that `/usr/local/lib` is listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf`,
or in one of the files included by `/etc/ld.so.conf`. If it's not, then
you can explicitly cache the shared libraries from `/usr/local/lib` by running
`ldconfig /usr/local/lib`, as root.

Comment: This solved my problem, but how do I configure cmake to install my software in `/lib` rather than `/usr/local/lib`.  Giving root as prefix seems absurd. I don't want unecessary folders in my root folder.

Answer (score 5):

First check LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable is having the path to your library directory

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

If not there then update the library path.

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/library
```

Use strace to debug.

```
strace -f ./run
```

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./run` try this

Comment: thanks for your support, but this doesn't do the trick either. Could this happen due to missing dependencies in the .so library?

Comment: 2 options you can try . 1 `strace` command and 2. `objdump -f /usr/local/lib/libMyLib.so | grep NEEDED`  and check the dependance library if exist.

Comment: Already checked out option 2. Option 1 shows an output like this: open("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libMyLib.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)\n
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp", 0x7eb967b8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) ..... It does this with several path combinations and checks several paths like /usr/lib, usr/local/lib, ... I'm checking the result on google right now

Comment: Two questions `open("/path/to/library/libMyLib.so")` does this come up in the `strace` and the permission of the `libMyLib.so` is same as other libraries.

Comment: Firstly, about your second question, how to check/set permissions of a library? 
Secondly, jep the strace genreates a lot of  these open() lines. Also just realized the first open() has the right path and seems to work: open("/usr/local/lib/libMyLib.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "...", 512) = 512
lseek(3, 152304, SEEK_SET)              = 152304
read(3, "...", 1120) = 1120
lseek(3, 152001, SEEK_SET)              = 152001
read(3, "...", 51) = 51
close(3). But this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807560/ldd-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-linked-binary check with this

Comment: Already found that one. readelf -A reveals that it Tag_Cpu_name: "7-A" and Tag_Cpu_arch: "v7". The CPU im running on has model Name: ARMv7 Rev 4 (v7l) and CPU architecture 7. Shouldn't These values Match?

Comment: what is the o/p of `ldd run`?

Comment: output is that it finds all the needed libraries to run it, except libMyLib.so. Like this: libMyLib.so => not found

Comment: Can you please try `strace ldd run` ?

Comment: strace -f ldd run return firstly an attempt to open the actual libMyLib.so: [pid  2747] open("/usr/lib/libMyLib.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
 After a few read() and seeks() calls it calls close(3). Then it start trying to open libMyLib.so again, but from a lot of different locations [pid  2747] open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libMyLib.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory). It does this with several paths (like it's brute forcing to find the right location)

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I also contacted the creators of libMyLib.so. Appearantly they gave me the wrong library in the first place. While the library was Arm v7 a indeed, it was not hard float. They gave me a new one and everything works fine.